# How to ignore elements in go template/text

Tags: go, templates, go-templates

I have a file that I convert through go template/text. The file contains a line that I want the template parser to ignore. This line contains keys with a very similar syntax than the template ones and it confuses the parser. It tries to interpret them but it should not.

Here is the confusing line:

```
GRAVATAR_SOURCE = https://{{ .Env.GRAVATARHOST }}
# Line I would like go template/text to ignore
ACCESS_LOG_TEMPLATE = {{.Ctx.RemoteAddr}} - {{.Identity}} {{.Start.Format "[02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700]" }} "{{.Ctx.Req.Method}} {{.Ctx.Req.RequestURI}} {{.Ctx.Req.Proto}}" {{.ResponseWriter.Status}} {{.ResponseWriter.Size}} "{{.Ctx.Req.Referer}}\" \"{{.Ctx.Req.UserAgent}}"
```

As you can see, GRAVATAR_SOURCE is succesfully parsed by go template/text but ACCESS_LOG_TEMPLATE breaks as it shouldn't be parsed (the template in this line being for a log parser).

How can I tell go template/text to ignore that line ?

I would like to use something equivalent to `{% raw %}{% endraw %}` in jinja2. That way, I can use any go binaries that have a template/text parser without the need to alter and recompile it.

Thanks.

Comment: With "template/text" you mean package "text/template", or?

Comment: Indeed. But I solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61121895/7920446

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found my answer.

According to https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Examples

I can wrap my ACCESS_LOG_TEMPLATE with:

```
{{`"output"`}}
```

That way:

```
GRAVATAR_SOURCE = https://{{ .Env.GRAVATARHOST }}
# Line I would like go template/text to ignore
{{`ACCESS_LOG_TEMPLATE = {{.Ctx.RemoteAddr}} - {{.Identity}} {{.Start.Format "[02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700]" }} "{{.Ctx.Req.Method}} {{.Ctx.Req.RequestURI}} {{.Ctx.Req.Proto}}" {{.ResponseWriter.Status}} {{.ResponseWriter.Size}} "{{.Ctx.Req.Referer}}\" \"{{.Ctx.Req.UserAgent}}"`}}
```

Comment: Yes, this works as long as the inner text doesn't contain a backtick.

Answer (score 4):

You may change the delimeters of what needs to be parsed, so the rest will be "ignored". You may use the [`Template.Delims()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims) method for that.

For example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Delims("[[", "]]").Parse(src))
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "Env": map[string]interface{}{
        "GRAVATARHOST": "xx",
    },
}
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

const src = `GRAVATAR_SOURCE = https://[[ .Env.GRAVATARHOST ]]
# Line I would like go template/text to ignore
ACCESS_LOG_TEMPLATE = {{.Ctx.RemoteAddr}} - {{.Identity}} {{.Start.Format "[02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700]" }} "{{.Ctx.Req.Method}} {{.Ctx.Req.RequestURI}} {{.Ctx.Req.Proto}}" {{.ResponseWriter.Status}} {{.ResponseWriter.Size}} "{{.Ctx.Req.Referer}}\" \"{{.Ctx.Req.UserAgent}}"
`
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-lqLFinE2DN)):

```
GRAVATAR_SOURCE = https://xx
# Line I would like go template/text to ignore
ACCESS_LOG_TEMPLATE = {{.Ctx.RemoteAddr}} - {{.Identity}} {{.Start.Format "[02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700]" }} "{{.Ctx.Req.Method}} {{.Ctx.Req.RequestURI}} {{.Ctx.Req.Proto}}" {{.ResponseWriter.Status}} {{.ResponseWriter.Size}} "{{.Ctx.Req.Referer}}\" \"{{.Ctx.Req.UserAgent}}"
```

Comment: It is not quite what I would like to do. Is there any comments elements in the go template/text project that can say to a parser to skip a portion ? Something equivalent to `{% raw %}{% endraw %}` in jinja2 ?

Comment: @MichéeLengronne There is a comment syntax like `{{/* comment */}}` but comments are not included in the output (completely stripped).

Comment: Yes, but it is not what I'm looking for either. I would like to have the ACCESS_LOG_TEMPLATE line untouched in the output.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne My solution achieves that. I don't know of an easier way.

Comment: Allright. Thanks. I will find another way to do it. To compile a fraction of code on top of a library is a bit much for just that and not flexible at all. Thanks again.